# Как передать дату в json формата dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: c#

есть класс json, который содержит свойство:

```
[JsonProperty("DocumentConsiderationDate", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? RequestDateClient { get; set; }
```

Я заполняю этот класс через sql запрос при помощи CONVERT(date, dci.CreationDate).
Но при отправке в soapui приходит такая дата:

```
"DocumentConsiderationDate": "2021-11-19T00:00:00",
```

Что я делаю не так?? я хочу, чтоб возвращалось "2021-11-19"

Comment: Нормальная дата в universal формате, стандарт. Зачем вам дата в формате, который можете прочитать только вы через наворачивание кучи аттрибутов в модель - не совсем понятно.

Comment: Укажите, что за сериализатор используете.

Comment: Вопрос снят, решили так оставить

Comment: И правильно сделали. :) Вы можете удалить пост, если хотите.